# How to find number of hits in actorSelection

Tags: scala, akka

I am making a scala akka based system which will dynamically add new actors (representing users) into an existing hierarchy, and I therefore need to know whether a given message should result in creating a new actor in the hierarchy (if it doesn't already exist) or not. I guess what I really want is some method like actorSelection which would return number of actors in resultset rather then the resultset itself.

The following code throws an exception if the actor already exists with this name:

```
case u:UserAdded   => {
  context.actorOf(Props[HashActor],u.user.hash()) ! u
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/akka-user/jnv1CrdPKns I guess this was a lot easier then I thought:

```
     case u:UserAdded =>
         val target = context.actorFor(u.user.hash) match {
           case noref if noref.isTerminated => context.actorOf(Props[HashActor], u.user.hash)    
           case ref => ref
         }
         target forward u
```

Comment: Why do you call actorFor twice?

Comment: oops, newbie mistake, You're right not necessary since I already have the ref